# Possible rounding error? C++

Tags: c++11

I'm still very new to c++, so forgive me if this should is an ignorant question. The purpose of this short code is to calculate a monthly car payment based on 6 user inputs.

Using these inputs, 623.72 is output, however I was expecting 626.81
Inputs, in order: 20000,
                  0.06,
                  1000,
                  100,
                  0.07,
                  36.

Can anyone shed any light on why my answer is slightly off? Am I running into a rounding error? Am I rounding in the wrong place or using a wrong variable type?
Thanks!

The formula for monthly payment is broken down into steps which made it easier to write. It's based off this formula:

monthly_payment =
Final_price_minus_downpayment * ( (monthly_rate * (1 + monthly_rate)^num_months / (1 + monthly_rate)^num_months - 1 )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::pow;
using std::fixed;
using std::setprecision;

int main() {

  //Initializing the 6 user inputs
  double carPrice;
  double salesTaxRate;
  double downPayment;
  double titleAndFees;
  double yearlyInterestRate;
  double loanDuration;

  //Getting the 6 user inputs
  cin >> carPrice;
  cin >> salesTaxRate;
  cin >> downPayment;
  cin >> titleAndFees;
  cin >> yearlyInterestRate;
  cin >> loanDuration;

  //Calculate the monthly Payment
  double salesTax = carPrice * salesTaxRate;
  double totalPrice = carPrice + salesTax;
  double finalPriceMinusDown = totalPrice - downPayment;
  double monthlyInterestRate = yearlyInterestRate / 12.0;

  //Formula broken down into steps
  double step1 = pow((1+monthlyInterestRate),loanDuration);
  cout << step1 << endl;
  double step2 = monthlyInterestRate * step1;
  cout << step2 << endl;
  double step3 = step1 - 1;
  cout << step3 << endl;
  double step4 = step2 / step3;
  cout << step4 << endl;
  double step5 = finalPriceMinusDown * step4;
  cout << step5 << endl;
  double monthlyPayment = step5;

  //cout << "The monthly payment is: ";
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << monthlyPayment;

}
```

Comment: Code screenshots are not very useful, please copy the code into the question.

Comment: I apologize, I know it wasn't the best way. I'm still getting a hang of the site. I'll work on editing it in.

Comment: In your formula there are 4 open parenthesis ("`(`") but only 3 closed ("`)`"). I suppose there is something wrong

Comment: You're right. It looks like a closing parentheses was simply missing from the end of the formula.

Comment: Please, can you check and report the exact formula? Written as is, you can simplify the part `(1 + monthly_rate)^num_months` that is numerator and in denominator; I suspect that the denominator isn't `(1 + monthly_rate)^num_months` but `((1 + monthly_rate)^num_months - 1)`

Comment: uhmmm... and, how is computed the `Final_price_minus_downpayment`? `titleAndFees` isn't involved?

Comment: Let me rewrite the formula so it makes sense for the code being used. I apologize at the disorganization of the post. I'll make sure to be better prepared next time.

Comment: monthly_payment =
finalPriceMinusDown * ( (monthlyInterestRate * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^loanDuration / (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^loanDuration - 1 )

Comment: I forgot to involve titleAndFees. This is a lesson in slowing down and paying closer attention as I code. Thank you for looking this over, I really do appreciate it!